# Does -g (or --debug) command option increase the loaded memory footprint?

Tags: c, clang, armclang

Does the `-g` (or `--debug`) clang command option increase the memory footprint of the compiled application? Specifically, does it change the binary size loaded on an embedded ARM system?

Note: I know the debug build adds symbol table and some more debug information to the ELF, but this should be used by the debugger, running on the host machine (say, a PC with Eclipse). Question is if it changes the size of the *loaded* image.

Comment: Tip: convert `.elf` file to `.bin` file. Does it change with `-g`? `an embedded ARM system?` The word "embedded" changes it's meaning - do you mean a _bare-metal_ embedded platform? Can you give an example of such system? Is raspberrypi3 or stm32 what you have in mind?

Comment: I guess the term "bare metal" is what you'd describe the system in question. It is a dev board encompassing an ASIC with an ARM core (and the accompanying ecosystem) embedded. We load the FW on the chip using the ARM Dev Studio debugger.

Comment: Usually you don't load `elf` directly on such a systems. Only the essential binary is stripped down and loaded.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - yes, which is what the debugger is doing.

Comment: @ysap Not necessarily. You might be able to flash your binary (generated with `fromelf` utility for example) to the target and it will run standalone still able to attach to a debugger. Then the debugger can load the corresponding symbols from the original ELF.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - yes, we do this occasionally, but anyway, it is not the ELF that's being loaded on the chip. As you noted, it is a stripped version (or, an image generated with different options, or using fromelf). In any case, it'd be the loader that will extract the loadable parts from the binary. I think we are in agreement.

Answer (score 5):

## No

The `-g` option only adds debug information in the binary, in sections which are *not* loaded into memory.  The actual code and data generated is not affected.

Try running `objdump -h` on both versions of the ELF binary.  You will see some sections marked with attribute `ALLOC` and others not.  Only those marked `ALLOC` are loaded or allocated memory at runtime.  You should observe that those sections have exactly the same size between both versions; indeed, they should have exactly the same contents, which you can verify with `objdump --full-contents` and `diff` if you like.   The only differences are in sections that are not marked `ALLOC`; these are not loaded into memory and have no effect at runtime.